# Заключение в кавычки имен полей при создании индекса

Tags: firebird, sql

Нужно ли заключать поля в кавычки при создании индекса, если эти поля содержат пробелы или символы "-" или "/", например, CREATE ASCENDING INDEX IDX_DELIVERY_FIRST_NAME ON DELIVERY(FIRST NAME), а также необходимо ли заключать имя индекса в кавычки , например , CREATE ASCENDING INDEX IDX_CLIENTS_STATE/PROVINCE ON CLIENTS("STATE/PROVINCE");?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, двойные кавычки в таких случаях - это требование стандарта.
В конкретной СУБД может потребоваться включение соответствующего параметра для их использования.

Comment: @msi, а в запросе
    CREATE ASCENDING INDEX IDX_CLIENTS_STATE/PROVINCE ON CLIENTS("STATE/PROVINCE");
нужно ли заключать в кавычки IDX_CLIENTS_STATE/PROVINCE (название индекса)? И что за параметр необходимо включить в Firebird для их использования?

Comment: Я полагаю, что нужно, хотя мне не вполне понятно, зачем вы даете индексу такое имя.
Насчет Firebird не скажу, но в SQL Server за это отвечает параметр 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER { ON | OFF }
Включен по умолчанию.